# Can you change difficulty mid-playthrough in The Bureau: XCOM Declassified?

Tags: the-bureau-xcom-declassified

At the start of The Bureau: XCOM Declassified I'm asked to pick a difficulty level. Is it possible to change the difficulty mid-playthrough after starting?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

At any point during a mission (but apparently not in the main menu), you can access options (esc), and go into game options, and the top option will be the difficulty choice.